# cljfx desktop program - how to set icon from .png file as resource?

Tags: javafx, clojure

- cljfx has Stage :icons https://github.com/cljfx/cljfx/blob/29aaef956b22cee774524912a3083ed651033f1b/src/cljfx/fx/stage.clj#L23
- what does not work

```clj
:["icon.png"]
:[(Image. "icon.png")]
```

how to set the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 :icons      [(javafx.scene.image.Image. "icon.png")]
```

, where `icon.png` is in the directory `resources`.